# How do I get PIL to work when built on mingw/cygwin?

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to build PIL 1.1.6 against cygwin or mingw whilst running against a windows install of python. When I do either the build works but I get the following failure when trying to save files.

```
$ python25
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 21 2008, 13:11:45) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL.Image import open
>>> im = open('test.gif')
>>> im.save('output1.gif')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1405, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py", line 291, in _save

    ImageFile._save(imOut, fp, [("gif", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 491, in _save
    s = e.encode_to_file(fh, bufsize)
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
>>>
```

I'm not compiling with the libraries for jpeg or zip support but I don't think this should be relevant here.

The failing line seems to be a write in encode_to_file in encode.c.

I'm suspiscious that this occurs because a file descriptor is being passed from Python (which was build under visual studio 2003) to _imaging.pyd but that the file descriptors don't match because on windows file descriptors are and abstraction on top of the operating system. Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from some cursory Google searching, you need to rebase the DLLs after building PIL in order for it to work properly on Cygwin.

References:

- **http://jetfar.com/cygwin-install-python-imaging-library/**
- **http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-06/msg01121.html**